# How to Extract Date from the column of type SECONDDATE on Hana DB

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

We have a table in the HANA DB with two columns of following data types

```
DeliveryDate : SECONDDATE// store values like : 2010-01-11 13:30:00
NewDeliveryDate : Date // will store values like: 2010-01-11
```

How to write sql script to extract the date value from the source column(DeliveryDate) to the target column (NewDeliveryDate) ?

Could you help us with suitable HANA SQL script function to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Assigning the date part of a seconddate data type to a date data type does not require using a SQLScript function.

It is sufficient to perform a type conversion and this can even be an implicit conversion during a value assignment.

```
// implicit conversion by assignment
// assigning the seconddate value to a date data type implicitly converts the value, leaving the date part

NewDeliveryDate = DeliveryDate;     

// explicit conversion 
// this is the preferred option as it makes the conversion explicit. 
NewDeliveryDate = to_date(DeliveryDate);
```

Check the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/e8e6c8142e60469bb401de5fdb6f7c00/1f17bf66e40740c882571e49b55058fd.html?locale=en-US&q=to_date) for details on the conversion functions.